# mouse and keyboard issue with 22.10 after update/upgrade

Tags: updates, keyboard, mouse, video, 22.10

i've been running 22.10 on a rog zephyrus m16 since October with very little issues to speak of save for some audio weirdness here and there.

yesterday i did an update/upgrade.... and suddenly my mouse cursor lags really bad. i have tried other devices, an optical mouse and a trackball. they all lag just as much as the touchpad. if i move it very very slowly then it tracks more or less but if i use anything resembling a normal speed it freezes and then jumps.

i've noticed just a little keyboard lag as well, but its not nearly as noticeable. i tried 23.04 daily and it did the same thing, tried openSUSE tumbleweed. same issue... so maybe the update/upgrade timing was just a coincidence? I'm just not sure what steps to take next. there's no cpu spikes or memory issues...but videos also do not seem to playback correctly on youtube (they were fine before) they seem to freeze on the first frame while audio plays...and when i pause it it goes to whichever frame i paused it at. this made me concerned it might be an issue with the video in "about" it indicates it is set to intel graphics...in the nvidia control panel its set to nvidia and intel is grayed out...this is also new. that doesn't really explain why the problem persisted on the liveUSB installers tho.

hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: just tried a 22.04.5 live usb... and the mouse works fine with that unlike the other 3 live usb releases i tried

Comment: installed 22.04.2 because the 22.04.5 installer kept locking up.... mouse worked fine on the installer, but after install everytime i moved the mouse the screen would blank out. installed the proprietary nvidia drivers and now the mouse is slow again. mouse works fine in the bios and worked fine in the installer.

Comment: so, i went and installed windows and everything is working properly in windows 11. i dont want to keep windows i just wanted to rule out hardware problems. i'd like to get back to the nicely working os i had for several months if at all possible. but it seems the problems are purely software hopefully someone can figure out what i should check next

Comment: possibly helpful information: its intel i7-12700h with an rtx 3060 nvidia.